# useState async problem (not updating/saving)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
}, [])

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10')
    const posts_data = await data.json()    
    setPosts(posts_data)
    console.log(posts)    
}
```

From the `console.log(posts)` it says `[]` with a `length: 0` inside. However when I console log `posts_data` it then gives me all the `posts` I got from that  api call. Is the `setPosts` not working?

**UPDATE**

I even added:

```
<div className="container-fluid mt-3">
    <h1 className="text-white">Posts</h1>
    {posts.map(post => {
        <p>asdasd</p>
    })}
</div>
```

And it doesn't display anything.

**UPDATE 2**

As suggested, I tried fetching the data on the parent component `App.js` and then sent it to my `Posts.js` component via props:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
}, [])

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10')
    const posts_data = await data.json()    
    setPosts(posts_data) 
} 

return (
  <Router>
  <div className="container-fluid pt-5">
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/posts" posts={posts} exact component={Posts} />
      </Switch>
```

And in my `Post.js`:

```
function Posts(props) {
  return (
        <div className="container-fluid mt-3">
            <h1 className="text-white">Posts</h1>
            {props.posts.map(post => {
                return <p key={post.id}>Hello</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And now it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I really have no idea why my first solution didn't worked, since I used this code the other day and it worked flawlessly without any problems. Now, it doesn't store anything (or maybe because of the async stuffs) it doesn't display all the data I got from that api.

Comment: Also, when I `console.log(posts_data)` it really gives me all the data from the api call.

Comment: What does ```console.log(data)``` and ```console.log(posts_data)``` output?

Comment: @yudhiesh `console.log(data)` says `Response {type...` and `console.log(posts_data)` gives me an array for all the posts from the api - `[0:{id:1, title: 'aaaaa'...}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setPosts sets the data asynchronously. That is why the `console.log` statement gets executed even before the setPosts finishes its job of setting the fetched content.
You can do this instead.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10"
    );
    const posts_data = await data.json();
    setPosts(posts_data);
    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log(posts);
    })
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

UPDATE:
You can do this for mapping out the posts...

```
<div className="container-fluid mt-3">
    <h1 className="text-white">Posts</h1>
    <div>{posts && posts.map(post => {
        return <p>asdasd</p>
    })}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed the code you gave me but it's still not appearing in the console. Also the mapping part doesn't display anything too.

Comment: Are you passing data from parent?

Comment: Watch this: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-matsumoto-2x8lg

Comment: This issue is **well-covered** by previous questions and answers on this topic. Please mark duplicates as duplicates, rather than posting answers. Help in the comments if you want to (that's always a great thing to do).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You should first read the question and find the actual problems in UPDATE 1 and UPDATE 2 before marking the question as duplicate just based on the first few lines. The problem should be solved, whenever a question is being asked here. It's the duty of every person including me to read and understand the real problem of the asker.

Comment: It's all working now! :) Thank you for everyone's help. Sorry for all the confusion, I just tried using React last night and coming from Vue, this is really different. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @spycbanda - It's also a duty not to fill the site with repetitive questions, as you [instructed the OP to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774001/usestate-not-saving-data?noredirect=1#comment114526423_64774001). Sometimes we just help in comments.

Comment: No issue @DranDev The community of React is very helpful and I assure you that you would learn React very quickly. Welcome to the community and all the best!

Comment: @spycbanda thank you so much once again! God bless! :)